# EF vs SP performance inserting multiple rows

Tags: mysql, performance, bulk-insert

I know of three most common ways of doing so:

1. Using a relation level as Entity Framework, which as far as I know has the worst performance.
2. Using a bulk insert, such as `INSERT INTO table1 (x,y) VALUES (x1,y1), (x2,y2)`
3. Using a stored procedure and calling it with a `DataSet` as a parameter.

What is considered to be the most efficient?

Comment: In SQL, batched insert (#2) and `LOAD DATA` are the fastest.

Comment: @Rick James I wrote, in MySQL, so you suggest load data from file? this seem ridicules for me. Is  that actually the suggested way? If i have multiple rows in my code, should I save them to a file and than load the file data???

Comment: Since you don't already have a file (as some people do), use "batch" ("bulk") insert of 100-1000 rows at a time.

Comment: @Rick James you mean method 2 right? stored procedure is not as fast/recommanded?

Comment: A stored proc would insert only one row at a time, no?

Comment: @Rick James , Exactly, is that only in mysql or other sql languages as well? isnt there an option to set a "table of values" as an input parameter?

Comment: MySQL Procs cannot take any type of "array" as an input argument.  Two exceptions:  You could fill a table with the array before calling the proc.  Or, you could have some kind of text string containing an array; this is messy to program.

Comment: But, since the purpose of the proc is to do inserts, it does not make sense to first insert the values in another table.